# Append Span Tag, after every 3rd div Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am looking for the solution to place a span tag, after every third div tag .

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid_15">
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Sun</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Mon</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Tue</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Wed</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Thu</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Fri</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Sat</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up">
            <div class="form-content-left">Morning</div>
            <div class="form-content-right">(7.00 - 8.00)</div>
            <span class="clear"></span><span class="clear"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Needed**

```
<div class="grid_15">
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Sun</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Mon</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Tue</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   **<span class="clear"></span>**
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Wed</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Thu</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Fri</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up"><span class="form-content-left">All Hours</span><span class="clear"></span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   **<span class="clear"></span>**
   <div class="grid_5">
      <p>Sat</p>
      <div>
         <div class="suggest nudge-up">
            <div class="form-content-left">Morning</div>
            <div class="form-content-right">(7.00 - 8.00)</div>
            <span class="clear"></span><span class="clear"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can See, the result has, span tag (**`<span class="clear"></span>`**), after every third div completion, I tried :

**jQuery**

```
var a = $('html').find('div.grid_15 > div.grid_5');
for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=3 ) {
a.slice(i, i+3).append('<span class="clear"></span>');
}
```

But not getting the result as expected,
here is the link :

http://jsfiddle.net/pxaS4/

please help me with solution.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child(3n)` selector:

```
$('div.grid_15 > div.grid_5:nth-child(3n)').after('<span class="clear">foo</span>');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pxaS4/2/**

Comment: +1 I was fiddling around with the modulus, but this is *definitely **much*** simpler.

Comment: My friend, thanks for this solution, but '<span class="clear">foo</span>' is inside a div '<span class="clear">foo</span></div>' , i required '<span class="clear">foo</span>' to be just above 4th '<div class="grid_5">', means span tag should be '</div><span class="clear">foo</span><div class="grid_5">',

Comment: @RaviMone: Isn't that what it does now? You might've taken the code before Joseph edited my answer.

Comment: hey, Used .after instead of .append, looks fine, is that corect.

Comment: Thanks a Lot to Joseph Silber and Blender,

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.grid_5').each(function(index){

if(((index+1)%3)==0)
{
$(this).after('<span class="clear"></span>');
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".grid_5").each(function (i) {
 if ((i+1)%3==0) $(this).after('<span class="clear"></span>');  
});
```

Comment: i think he wants to add  span after the div , not to append