# Add div after every third post

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this post which does what I want:
[Append Span Tag, after every 3rd div Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372545/append-span-tag-after-every-3rd-div-jquery)
http://jsfiddle.net/pxaS4/2/

But I am using a three column layout. I'd like to clear:both after every third post so that if they differ in height, they will always stay 3 to a row.

html:

```
<div class="post-listing">

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height. This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height. 
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height. This text make the post-item different height. This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height. This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height. This text make the post-item different height. This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

    <div class="post-item">
    This text make the post-item different height.
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
  color: #000;
}

.post-listing {
  width: 300px;
}

.post-listing .post-item {
  float: left;
  color: red;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 32%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.post-listing :nth-child(3n+0).post-item {
  margin-right: 0%;
  clear: right;
}
```

This seems to be working fine. The issue is when I try to add a div class"clear" with jquery after every third post. This is what I have and it's not working:

```
$('div.post-listing > div.post-item:nth-child(3n)').after('<div class="clear">this is the clear class</div>');
```

jsfiddle (non-working) here:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/936qtbu5/)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle didn't have jQuery loaded. Seems to do what you want when you add jQuery? https://jsfiddle.net/936qtbu5/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add new `div`s. Add `clear: left` to `3n+1` `.post-item`.

```
.post-item:nth-child(3n+1) {clear: left;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/936qtbu5/1/

Comment: That's way easier than what I was trying to do...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, the reason your jQuery is not working is that jQuery is not being loaded in your fiddle. If you load the latest jQuery framework, your jQuery code works fine.

Second, what you're looking to do can be accomplished in just CSS.

You can target each 3rd item and remove its margin-right like so:

```
.post-listing .post-item:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

You can also clear the first item of each new row like so:

```
.post-listing .post-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Since there are three items in each row, we put `3n`.
This means that regardless of how many rows you have, you will always be targeting the correct number of items.
The `+1` will grab the *next* `.post-listing` item after the last item in the previous row.

For example, say you have two rows, with 3 items in each row.
Using `nth-child(3n+1)` will select items number 1 and 4.

The first iteration of n is 0.
(3 * 0) + 1 = 1

The second iteration of n is 1.
(3 * 1) + 1 = 4

Here is the link to the updated fiddle with just CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/936qtbu5/4/